# WPF Move two windows together

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have two types of windows: *Main* and *Child*. When I move main, all child windows must move also. All my windows have style `None`, so I use `DragMove`. For moving child I use `LocationChange` of *Main*. And if I start moving main window fast, child move with some delay. My windows are stick one to another, so when moving main window fast, some gaps appears. 
I use this question 
[Move two WPF windows at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445082/move-two-wpf-windows-at-once)

How can I reduce this gaps?

some code:

```
    private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        StickyWindow.ParentWndStartMove(this);
        this.DragMove();
    }
```

here I move all children

```
    public static void ParentWndMove(Window parentWindow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < windowsToMove.Length; i++)
        {
            if (windowsToMove[i])
            {
                windows[i].Top += -(parentWindowPosition.Y - parentWindow.Top);
                windows[i].Left += -(parentWindowPosition.X - parentWindow.Left);
            }
        }

        parentWindowPosition.X = parentWindow.Left;
        parentWindowPosition.Y = parentWindow.Top;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make an assumption based on your code fragment that **parentWindowPosition**
is a struct or class that has X and Y initialized to the Left and Top values of your MainWindow.

If that is the case then only thing you need to do in your MouseLeftButtonDown handler is call DragMove()

```
private void MainWindow_OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, 
                                              MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DragMove();
}
```

Register a handler on the LocationChanged event of your MainWindow.

```
LocationChanged += MainWindow_OnLocationChanged;
```

which calls your ParentWndMove() method

```
private void MainWindow_OnLocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ParentWndMove(sender as Window)
}
```

This code works on my system with no delays no matter how quickly I drag the main window and the window positions never get out of sync.

**NOTE:** The ParentWndMove() method you posted has some compile time errors. I'm posting a fixed version for reference

```
public static void ParentWndMove(Window parentWindow)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < windowsToMove.Length; i++)
    {
        if (windowsToMove[i] != null)
        {
            windowsToMove[i].Top += -(parentWindowPosition.Y - parentWindow.Top);
            windowsToMove[i].Left += -(parentWindowPosition.X - parentWindow.Left);
        }
    }

    parentWindowPosition.X = parentWindow.Left;
    parentWindowPosition.Y = parentWindow.Top;
}
```

Comment: Added sample project here:
[sourse](https://mega.co.nz/#!ExcRVTJS!Rv3_dhqiLQry3KSRaQjIX1H_AY4PKdIxmiuyPEhPHO0)
If i move fast i can see phone picture between two windows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did:

I first set an Instance of the Parent as the owner of the Child window, (make an instance by setting it in the ParentWindow class `public static ParentWindow instance;` then `instance = this;`) :

```
public ChildWindow()
{
    Owner = ParentWindow.instance;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Then I add an event handler in the Parent Class to fire when the Parent is moving:

```
public ParentWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LocationChanged += new EventHandler(Window_LocationChanged);
}
```

Now I loop through all the windows owened by the ParentWindow to reset their margin:

```
private void Window_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Window win in this.OwnedWindows)
    {
        win.Top = this.Top + ((this.ActualHeight - win.ActualHeight) / 2);
        win.Left = this.Left + ((this.ActualWidth - win.ActualWidth) / 2);
    }
}
```